# Mysql UPDATING statement in datetime

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i know its kind of weird but mind if somebody there look for this...

i have a 2 table which is

tableA 
id |  name | datetime -> format is int(11), varchar(128) datetime() 
1 | 'foo bar' | '2014-08-04 00:53:16''

tableB 
id | name | datetime | -> format is the same 
1 | 'foo bar ' | null

using this statement 
`UPDATE tableA a 
inner join tableB b on b.name = a.name 
SET a.datetime = b.datetime`

its say 
`Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect time value: '840:53:16'`;

 what the... :)

if i select this using its own format  

`select * from  tableA a inner join tableB b on b.name = a.name`

 its show 
id | name | datetime |id | name | datetime | 
1 | 'foo bar' | '2014-08-04 00:53:16'' | 1 | 'foo bar ' | null 
am i doing something wrong??
if i use

`show create table tableA
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`list_of_in`(`
id`int(11) NOT NULL,`
name`varchar(128) NOT NULL,`
datetime`datetime NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1`

`show create table tableB
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`list_of_in`(`
id`int(11) NOT NULL,`
name`varchar(128) NOT NULL,`
datetime`datetime NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1`

by the way , im creating store procedure right now and its working in my localhost 
but when i try it to the server, its not working and, after 6 hours i found out 
that this is the part that is not working...

by the way thanks for reading eheheh :))

Comment: Naming the column the same as the datatype.. maybe not such a good idea? And what kind of 'time' is '40:53:16'?

Comment: hehehe sorry about that its '2014-08-04 00:53:16' hehehehe going to edit it

Comment: Edit the post and include a 'show create table tableA' (and tableB)

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate your problem.

I recreated your tables, and when I run your query, it replaces tableA's datetime with the null from tableB. I'm guessing that you've built a simplified model of what is actually happening in your database? If that's the case, then the model you've made no longer highlights the problem.

What I did notice though, is that the error you are getting, is suggesting that the date format for one field doesn't match the other. I would check that both fields are in fact datetime, and that one isn't actually a varchar with the date in it.

Here's the dump of the sql to create my testing environment. If you run this (which will wipe TableA and TableB BTW), then run the query yourself, it should succeed.

```
# Dump of table tableA
# ------------------------------------------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tableA`;

CREATE TABLE `tableA` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

LOCK TABLES `tableA` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tableA` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `tableA` (`id`, `name`, `datetime`)
VALUES
    (1,'foobar','2014-08-04 00:53:16');

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tableA` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;


# Dump of table tableB
# ------------------------------------------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tableB`;

CREATE TABLE `tableB` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

LOCK TABLES `tableB` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tableB` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `tableB` (`id`, `name`, `datetime`)
VALUES
    (1,'foobar',NULL);

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tableB` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: after 11 hours of debugging i got nothing hehehehe, i voted up your answer because ur explanation is correct and thanks for the effort hehehehehe... its only means i dont have any mistake on my side im going to backup all my files and reinstall my lampp server my last resort hopes something is wrong there hahaha.. :)

Comment: i guess the problem was when i upgrade ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 something happen and after reinstaling my lampp , this bug does not exist anymore :(